# Работа с датой

Tags: mysql

Хочу получить такой ответ. Как это сделать? Даны даты: '2011-09-01', '2011-12-31'.

```
 id    |date
-------+-------------
  1    | '2011-09-01'
  2    | '2011-09-02'
  3    | '2011-09-03'
  4    | '2011-09-04'
...
  ?    | '2011-12-31'
```

Comment: Или может кто-инбудь составить цикл с функцией INTERVAL + 1 DAY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, как пример ( данные пишутся во временную таблицу, процедура самоудаляется ):

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `test` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date` date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  );

  delimiter //;
  CREATE PROCEDURE `date_between` ( dfrom DATE, dto DATE )
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE curr DATE;
    SET curr = dfrom;
    WHILE ( curr <  dto ) DO 
      INSERT INTO `test` VALUES ( NULL, curr );
      SET curr = curr + INTERVAL 1 day;
    END WHILE;
  END//;
  delimiter ;
  call date_between('2011-09-01', '2011-12-31');

  DROP PROCEDURE `date_between`;

  SELECT * FROM `test`;
```

Comment: Уррраааааааааааааааааа!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Получилось!
Спасибо, timka_s.
Кстати, у кого ошибка в Денвере #1436 возникает, исправьте в файле my.cnf thread_stack = 256K. Ато у меня ругался.

Answer (score 0):

если ты хочешь вывести все даты между теми что написал используй 
SELECT 'id=1' BETWEEN 'id=?'; под знаком вопроса id конечной даты которая у тебя в таблице

Comment: друг человека, спасибо за совет. Но он годится для случая когда таблица уже создана и известно число записей. А мне интересен случай когда таблица пуста изначально.

Comment: SELECT имя БД FROM `имя таблици` WHERE (`date` BETWEEN "2011-09-01" AND "2011-12-31")

Comment: Вай, только не between!!! Это медленно! Юзайте (`date`>={yourdate} AND `date`<={yourdate2}) чтобы узнать диапазон.
А вообще, погуглить и открыть 1ю ссылку было бы тоже неплохо, там всё расписано как с датами обращаться http://mysql.ru/docs/man/DATETIME.html .
П.с. Вот не помню кто меня научил, но я не отступаю от использования Unix-дат. Как-то всё с ними так хорошо, что больше ничего не надо!